# How to join two table based on one unique column in PostGIS

Tags: postgis

I wonder if there any simple query that perform just like Join features of ArcGIS Desktop.

Answer (score 6):

Just like they taught you in your SQL course:

```
SELECT table_a.*, table_b.*
FROM table_a JOIN table_b ON (table_a.id = table_b.id);
```

Comment: Thank You. It returns the query but I want to add a column in table_B from tacble_A. How can I do this?

Comment: @DevilsDream Here's a related question that discusses what a LEFT JOIN in postgresql is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11739324/what-is-a-left-join-in-postgresql